# How can I make test data files accessible to pytest tests when run with tox?

Tags: pytest, tox

I want to run a `test` for a function which accepts a [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) to a file as input via an argument: `function(some_path_to_file)` via `tox`. The file I want to pass to the function cannot be created temporarily during test setup (what I usually do via [`pytest`s builtin `tmpdir` fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html?highlight=tmpdir#the-tmpdir-fixture)) but resides in the package `<package>/data` directory besides the test directory `<package>/tests` (the location `<package>/tests/data` would probably be better). Because `tox` runs the tests in a virtualenv it's not clear to me how to make the test data file available to the test. I know that I can define the base temporary directory of `pytest` with the [`--basedir` option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html?highlight=tmpdir#the-default-base-temporary-directory) but I did not get it working with `tox` yet.

**tl;dr**

The problem was a conversion of `some_path_to_file` from `Path` to `str` (to pass it to [`sqlite3.connect(database`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite3#sqlite3.connect) inside the `function`) using [`Path.resolve(`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=path#pathlib.Path.resolve). No need to configure pytests `--basedir` option and `tox` in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tripped me up as well. The way I was able to solve it was to *specify the full path* of the text file I wanted the testing function to read *relative* to the base directory.

So for example, my directory tree looks like this:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── calculate_stats.py
├── my_package.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── requires.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── bin
│   └── calculate_stats
├── requirements
│   ├── default.txt
│   └── development.txt
├── setup.py
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test_calculate_stats.csv
│   ├── test_calculate_stats.txt
│   └── test_calculate_stats.py
└── tox.ini
```

In the file `test_calculate_stats.py` I have the following line:

```
assert (calculate_stats.calculate_stats_to_csv("test/test_calculate_stats.txt", "test/test_calculate_stats.csv") == 60)
```

The `calculate_stats_to_csv` function reads in the `test/test_calculate_stats.txt` file, calculates some stats, and outputs them to `test/test_calculate_stats.csv`

Initially I had just specified the input file to be `test_calculate_stats.txt` because it's in the same directory as the file containing the testing function -- that's when I ran into the error.

Comment: What have you passed to pytest via --basedir option in tox?

Comment: Nothing actually -- in `tox.ini` I have `commands =
 unit: pytest -v test`

My `pytest` doesn't seem to recognize `--basedir`. The `pytest` I am using is version 4.0.0 and I'm running python v3.7.1

Comment: In my specific use case I am connecting to a database in the function via [connect(database, ...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) accepts a [path like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object). Previously I converted `Path` to `str` and passed it to `connect(database`. I changed the production code from `function(some_path_to_file: Path)` to `function(some_path_to_file: str)` and removed the conversion. The function reads the file correctly and the test runs. Still wondering why the Path to str conversion worked w.o. tox

Comment: ... figured it out: In the conversion of the file path `some_path_to_file` from `Path` to `str` I used `str(Path.resolve(...))` to get full path and pass it to `connect(` as `str`. If one uses relative path conversion `str(Path(...))` it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`tox` predfines a number of [substitutions](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#substitutions). The directory of the virtualenv is `{envdir}`, `site-packages` is at `{envsitepackagesdir}`. Pass a value from the command line to your test script like this:

```
[testenv]
    commands = pytest --basedir={envsitepackagesdir}/mypackage
```

Comment: It's still not clear to me how the test code should look like?

Comment: Pass `{envsitepackagesdir}` or any substitution to your code; the code should use the passed value to calculate relative path to the data. For more details provide [mcve].

Comment: MCVE is minor due to example in answer below.